# how to loop throught select tags inside *ngFor and get the selected value

Tags: angular7

I have select tags inside a table with *ngFor and I want to loop for every select tag and get the selected value and then changed if it matches some condition 
I am working with angular 7 and I have tried to get the select tag with element ref and then change it's value but that changed all the select tags value and I only want to change a specific  select tag value

```html
<tr *ngFor="let categorymap of categoriesMap | orderBy:   order:reverse:'case-insensitive'">
            <td scope="row " class="goSubcategory point imageHeader rep-table">
              {{categorymap.saltEdgeCategory}}
            </td>
            <td scope="row" class="point rep-table"  >
              <div class=" m-auto mt-4">
                <select id="e" #e="ngModel" class="browser-default custom-select"   [(ngModel)]="categorymap.category" (click)="oldSelect = categorymap.category"  (change)="mapCategory($event,categorymap.id,categorymap.saltEdgeCategory,categorymap.category)" >
                    <option disabled hidden [value]="null">{{"pages.notMappedYet" | translate}}</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let category of categories"  [value]="category.name" >
                      {{category.name}}
                    </option>
                  </select>
            </div>
            </td>
             </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your click method `(click)="oldSelect = categorymap.category"` inside `<option>`, as categorymap.category belongs to category which is not available in `<select>` and for loop start inside `<option>` use this -

```
<option *ngFor="let category of categories" (click)="oldSelect = category.name" [value]="category.name" >
                  {{category.name}}
                </option>
```